# AttributeError: module 'pysynth' has no attribute 'make_wav'

Tags: python

AttributeError: module 'pysynth' has no attribute 'make_wav'

```py
import pysynth as ps
test = (('c', 4), ('e', 4), ('g', 4), ('c5', -2), ('e6', 8), ('d#6', 2))
ps.make_wav(test, fn = "test.wav")
```

Comment: Okay, so what is your question? What do you think should happen instead when you run the code, and *specifically why* do you think this should happen?

Answer (score 2):

pip version pysynth of pysynth is outdated. If you installed pysynth through pip, uninstall it, and install from github repository.

```
pip uninstall pysynth

git clone https://github.com/mdoege/PySynth.git

cd PySynth

python3 setup.py install
```